# __VA_ARGS__ expansion fails if preceded by scope

Tags: c++11, visual-studio-2015

I want to use `__VA_ARGS__` in a macro to get the equivalent of writing several lines of `if(a==b) return c`.

When compiling "small sample", it fails with

```
identifier "name2" is undefined (Line 18)
C2065 'name3': undeclared identifier (Line 18)
C2065 'name2': undeclared identifier (Line 18)
```

if both `USE_ENUM_CLASS` and `USE_VARIADIC_CONVERTER` are defined.

## A bit of rambling

I found information about previous versions of Visual Studio failing to expand `__VA_ARGS__`, but since the code works fine with an `enum` instead of an `enum class` I guess Visual Studio 2015 did fix at least some of the previous issues. In a real application I would use similar macros more then once, so this could save me a lot of lines and protect against forgetting to add code for 
enum values added later (adding to `NAME_LIST` would be sufficient).

## Small sample

This causes the mentioned error. Comment out either line that defines `USE_ENUM_CLASS` or `USE_VARIADIC_CONVERTER` and it will compile.

```
#define NAME_LIST name1,name2,name3
#define USE_ENUM_CLASS
#define USE_VARIADIC_CONVERTER

#ifdef USE_ENUM_CLASS
enum class e
#else
enum e
#endif
{
    name1, name2, name3
};

e int_to_e(int const i)
{
#ifdef USE_VARIADIC_CONVERTER
#define POPULATE_INT_TO_E(...) if(i==static_cast<int>(e::__VA_ARGS__)) return e::__VA_ARGS__;
    POPULATE_INT_TO_E(NAME_LIST);
#else
#define POPULATE_INT_TO_E(x) if(i==static_cast<int>(e::x)) return e::x
    POPULATE_INT_TO_E(name1);
    POPULATE_INT_TO_E(name2);
    POPULATE_INT_TO_E(name3);
#endif
    throw - 1;
}

void main(void)
{
}
```

## Further observations

The same error occurs when replacing the enum definition with

```
struct e
{
    enum
    {
        name1, name2, name3
    };
};
```

or

```
namespace e
{
    enum
    {
        name1, name2, name3
    };
}
```

or

```
namespace e
{
    int const name1 = 1;
    int const name2 = 2;
    int const name3 = 3;
};
```

## Question

**How can I rewrite/expand the macro to avoid these errors?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this fails is because `__VA_ARGS__` does not do what you think. I suspect that you're expecting variadic-template-like behaviour (duplicating the whole expression while expanding the pack), but it actually simply dumps all of the arguments in-place.

So when `POPULATE_INT_TO_E(NAME_LIST)` (the variadic version) gets expanded, you get:

```
if(i==static_cast<int>(e::name1, name2, name3))
    return e::name1, name2, name3;
```

This fails to work with an `enum class` because its members are scoped, and only `e::name1` is a valid qualified reference to the `name1` member: the others aren't available with their unqualified name.

This changes with `enum`, though: an `enum` exports its members into the enclosing scope, so both `e::name1` and `name2` reference members. Then, the expression is parsed as several values separated by comma operators. Now that's syntactically valid, but still doesn't do what you want -- it only handles `name3`.

---

Now what can we do to actually fix it? Iterating with the preprocessor is non-trivial, because it lacks any form of loops and recursion is hard to get in place.

But a common technique that's both simple and powerful is X-macros. Instead of listing your data on its own, pre-wrap it inside an `X` (or whatever you fancy) macro:

```
#define NAME_LIST \
    X(name1) \
    X(name2) \
    X(name3)
```

Then you can define `X`, expand `NAME_LIST`, and you'll have the behaviour you're after:

```
#define X(name_) \
    if(i==static_cast<int>(e::name_)) return e::name_;

NAME_LIST

#undef X
```

... expands to:

```
if(i==static_cast<int>(e::name1)) return e::name1;
if(i==static_cast<int>(e::name2)) return e::name2;
if(i==static_cast<int>(e::name3)) return e::name3;
```

Answer (score 0):

One another answer is iterating **VA_ARGS**.

```
#define NAME_LIST e::name1,e::name2,e::name3
#define USE_ENUM_CLASS
#define USE_VARIADIC_CONVERTER

#ifdef USE_ENUM_CLASS
enum class e
#else
enum e
#endif
{
    name1, name2, name3
};

e int_to_e(int const i)
{
#ifdef USE_VARIADIC_CONVERTER
#define POPULATE_INT_TO_E(...) \
    e _arr[] = {__VA_ARGS__}; \
    int _i; \
    for (_i = 0; _i < sizeof(_arr)/sizeof(_arr[0]); _i++) { \
      if(i==static_cast<int>(_arr[_i])) return _arr[_i]; \
    }
    POPULATE_INT_TO_E(NAME_LIST);
#else
#define POPULATE_INT_TO_E(x) if(i==static_cast<int>(e::x)) return e::x
    POPULATE_INT_TO_E(name1);
    POPULATE_INT_TO_E(name2);
    POPULATE_INT_TO_E(name3);
#endif
    throw - 1;
}

int main(void)
{
}
```

But you must define NAME_LIST as `e::name1,e::name2,e::name3`